# add one each time function is called --- string + number

Tags: javascript, counting

Each time I call this function. I want the output to increase by one. The problem is my variable is a string...

Better explanation (maybe)

1. call function
2. alert says 1
3. call function again
4. alert says 2
5. call function again
6. alert says 3
7. and so on..

How to get it like that!?

here's my code so far...

```
function addLink(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks') <= 1){
  localStorage.setItem('howManyLinks', localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks') + 1)
  }
  else{
    localStorage.setItem('howManyLinks', '1');
  }
  alert(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks'))
}
```

thanks from me ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string into a number then:

```
Number(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks')) + 1
```

You can also use the unary `+` operator to force the conversion

```
+localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks') + 1
```

I personally dislike using it, but many people prefer it.

The reason this is necessary is because `+` on a string is concatenation, so `'1' + 1` will return `'11'`.

Comment: Might find this useful (js perf of different casting methods): http://jsperf.com/best-of-string-to-number-conversion/10

Comment: You will have to make hundreds of thousands of calls for this to be remotely relevant. It is micro-optimization and if you are struggling so much that you need to do that, you *usually* have way bigger problems. Something like `Number()` makes code more readable than some bit-shifting "voodoo" and readability is more important than a microsecond.

Comment: Thanks alot! :D but when i call it the third time it gets back to 1 again.. i guess something is wrong with this line.. if(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks') <= 1)

Comment: @user2971409 The logic is off: "if `howManyLinks` is *smaller* or equal to one, increment by one." You need `>=` instead.

Comment: @IngoBürk - you're right, it's provided to show the number of different methods available, rather than inform on which one is best!

Answer (score -2):

you'll have to cast that string back to a number...
there's load of ways to do this (http://jsperf.com/best-of-string-to-number-conversion/10)
I use ">>0"

```
function addLink(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks') <= 1){
    localStorage.setItem('howManyLinks', (localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks')>>0) + 1)
  }
  else{
    localStorage.setItem('howManyLinks', 1);
  }
  alert(localStorage.getItem('howManyLinks'))
}
addLink(); //alerts 1
addLink(); //alerts 2
addLink(); //alerts 3
addLink(); //alerts 4
```

Comment: `localStorage` always stores data as strings…